# How to find 2nd and 3rd td's within a table row after finding the first td using jquery?

Tags: jquery

This works:

```
       $("#topTable tr[data-mainRow]:even").find("td:first").addClass("zibraBackground");
```

However, how can I identify the additional td's within this row, example, td 2 and td 3 using the method above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use CSS-like `:nth-child(k)`. Example:

```
var tr = $("#topTable tr[data-mainRow]:even");
tr.find("td:nth-child(1)").doSomething();
tr.find("td:nth-child(2)").doSomething();
tr.find("td:nth-child(3)").doSomething();
```

The indexes start at 1 not 0.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking is the pseudo selector `:eq(n)` where n is the index of the element you want to get.

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/